# efining a constant that always returns a specific folder

Tags: php, filepath

I am using a self-made framework with various directories, and I would like to create a `constant` which basically outputs the directory where my application folder is situated. 
I could accomplish this by declaring

**`define("DOC_ROOT", "/var/www/html/public/my-site.tld/");`**

somewhere in my `public/index.php` file, but for some reason, I would like to use a combination of `__DIR__, realpath(), dirname()...` as I still don't know why it is not working for me.

For now, let's assume this is a the folder structure I am using.

```
my-site.tld/
  src/
    public/
       index.php
    app/
       configs/
          constants.php/
       views/
       controllers/
       bootstrap.php
```

Since the `bootstrap.php` requires the `constants.php` first, and then `index.php` loads the `bootstrap.php` as shown

```
// public/index.php
require '../boostrap.php`;
```

We can assume this constants are the first to run, within the application. Now, the problem is that declaring a doc root which outputs just the full path to my-site.tld or in other words

> #### /var/www/html/public/my-site.tld/

has become impossible to me, partly because echoing `DOC_ROOT` would give out different paths in different files. So, I am asking is there a way to just define `DOC_ROOT` in the constants file, and wherever it is called, it will always output the main application folder as opposed to doing it manually like

**`define("DOC_ROOT", "/var/www/html/public/my-site.tld/");`**

Which require me to manually change that path everything I make changes or rename my folders.

Answer (score 0):

Store the URL in a standard constant:

```
define("CONSTANTNAME",     "VALUE");
```

[PHP Constant Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Comment: @Jezzabeans Sorry, that is what I actually did. But the problem is not that as you can read. It is not being able to define an absolute path that holds the path to the application everywhere it is used.

Comment: @Context - your problem obviously isn't very clearly stated.... if you are defining your constant in that way, then it should have the same value wherever it is referenced.... a constant, by definition, cannot change during the course of script execution.... it should not have different values in different files.... explain what you mean by `"but for some reason, I would like to use a combination of __DIR__, realpath(), dirname()..."`

Comment: @MarkBaker That is the point. I don't want to define it that way. I just want some method with the combination of `__DIR__, realpath(), dirname()` ... that produce the same result. If I did it manually as show in the example, it means, if one day I decided to change `/var/www` to `/home/sites/www` then it means I have to change the constant too.

Comment: As your constants.php file is 3 folders down (src, app and configs) from the level you want to define: `define("DOC_ROOT", realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../..'));` or you could have 3 nested `dirname()` calls instead of the 3 `/..`

Comment: @MarkBaker [this is the approach](https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.3/master/index.php#L57) I am trying to use for my app. Or something like that given the structure of my application.